# Get label under a row use the full width of the table

Tags: css, html-table, label, row

I am using jqxValidator to validate a group of radio buttons. When the red message (which is a label) appears under the row, it inherits the width of the first column, breaking the design:

[image]

I tried many things, finally changing the display of the label fixes the table layout, but the message get splitted in 2 lines.

Is there a way to extend the width of the label to use the whole table width?

Example: https://codepen.io/lhernand/pen/OEZbXb

HTML:

```
<table style="border:0; border-collapse:collapse; " width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="rowRequired jqx-validator-error-element" id="optionsID0EYE">
            <td style="border:0; width:50%; "><input id="ID0EYE" name="Patient-MainGP" value="true" type="radio"><span> Yes</span></td>
            <td style="border:0; width:50%; "><input style="margin-left:20px; " id="ID0EYE" name="Patient-MainGP" value="false" type="radio"><span> No</span></td>
        </tr><label class="jqx-validator-error-label" style="position: relative; left: 0px; width: 304.688px; top: 2px;">Please choose one option!</label>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Note: it should work in IE11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with this kind of fixed structure requires some mayor hacking,
since jquery validator inserts a label after a td on the table, the element behave like a td with no match on the same row.

Using the chrome dev tools option to copy the selector on the inspector, I can get the most specific selector posible for the html structure you have, so aplying a 200% size to this element, tricks the table to not missbehave

```
#tablePatientDetailsContainer > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > label{
  width: 200% !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Tested on Chrome, FF and Safari

My Working Code
https://codepen.io/Teobis/full/vrjZVR/

Hope this helps

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. I tried setting the width to 100%, but actually the width=200% is the real trick, incredible. I tested in IE11 and it worked perfect. The box-sizing is no needed. I also liked the idea to use an specific selector, to avoid conflicts. Good trick. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You placed the id `optionsID0EYE` in the wrong place. jqxValidator will create a sibling for the element who has this id. You need to do something like so:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="rowRequired">
        <div id="optionsID0EYE" style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap">
            <div style="width: 50%">
                <input id="ID0EYE" name="Patient-MainGP" value="true" type="radio"><span> Yes</span>
            </div>

            <div style="width: 50%">
                <input style="margin-left:20px; " id="ID0EYE" name="Patient-MainGP" value="false" type="radio"><span> No</span>
             </div>
         </div>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
```

I moved the id `optionsID0EYE` to a new `div` I made.

Working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YvLZeB?editors=1000

Comment: Thanks, now the message is displayed in 1 line, however it is still breaking the design, if you put a longer message like this "Please choose one of the options!", you will see that the first column get wider.

Comment: I changed the whole answer

Comment: Thanks for your help. First, I cannot change any element in the HTML because it's a big form generated from a XML using an XSLT transformation. Using your approach works fine but the red border has gone. I am using jqxValidator which by default is validating controls, but with a custom rule to validate the whole row of radio buttons, so I need the red border in the row. One thing that maybe I can do, is to apply some jquery (.wrap) to add a <div> to the label, so it will behave as a div.